# Facts about element 173

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms, elements

I am watching a video about element 173 being the biggest and last element that can ever be assembled.  The reason given as the last element that can be created is that the electrons would have to orbit faster than the speed of light for an element 174 to be allowed.

I have 2 questions concerning element 173....

1. If the electrons for 173 have to travel just under C, than does relativity come into play as far as the mass of the electrons?  I think I have read somewhere, where the mass of an electron at 90% the speed of light is something on the order of 11MeV and at 99.99999992% C they are 4GeV...(I think that is what I read, though I could be wrong)....  If so (or close),  would this not make the electron shell heavier than the nucleus?
2. This second question is a little harder...  Would 173 be in the "stable" zone for super heavy elements?  Could we calculate its half life ahead of time?

Comment: Do you have references?

Comment: There's no way we can comment on a video that we haven't seen and that you haven't identified. Please put some effort into finding written sources of information that we can refer to and discuss. Basically this video is making a semiclassical argument that isn't really correct. The real quantum-mechanical treatment would involve instability of the vacuum, and has nothing to do with electrons going faster than $c$.

Comment: @BenCrowell   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_GZzOJcWR4

Answer (score 4):

The account you've seen is a bit of a simplification. Electrons don't orbit atoms like planets orbiting the Sun, so they don't have an orbital velocity. Instead the electron is more like a cloud spread out over the atom.

The electron doesn't have a kinetic energy in the sense a macroscopic particle does, but we can calculate the average kinetic energy (technically the [expectation value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_value_(quantum_mechanics)) of the KE) from the wavefunction. You could associate a velocity with this KE using the relativistic equation for the KE:

$$ T = (\gamma - 1)mc^2 $$

where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor:

$$ \gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}} $$

Though this velocity doesn't have any physical significance for the electron in an atom. Note that the velocity calculated in this way will always be less that the speed of light no matter how large the kinetic energy is.

The calculation referred to was originally done by the notorious Richard Feynman using the relativistic Dirac equation to calculate the wavefunction of the hydrogen atom. Feynman assumed the nucleus was a point particle, and what he found was that for $Z > 137$ there is no longer a bound state. It isn't the case that the electron would have to be moving faster than light, just that the kinetic energy becomes so high that the wavefunction becomes oscillatory rather than looking like a $1s$ orbital. Unfortunately I cannot find this calculation published anywhere, even though it is widely referred to. It appears to be something that Feynman did just for fun.

However Feynman assumed the nucleus is a point particle, and for these highly bound states the physical size of the nucleus matters. The calculation has been repeated for the (expected) real size of the nucleus and this extends the upper limit to $Z=173$ (the fact this has the same digits as $137$ is a coincidence). It is not the case that the electron becomes unbound above $Z=173$, but rather that once the electron energy significantly exceeds its rest mass energy the number of electrons present becomes vaguely defined. Quantum field theory allows energy and particles to be interchanged, and the consequence is that once the energies are high enough new particles can be created so the number of particles present is not well defined. I'm not sure if the physics for $Z > 173$ is fully understood even today.

As for your second question, the anticipated [island of stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability) for nuclei is somewhere around $Z=114$ to $Z=126$. It isn't known accurately since calculating the wavefunctions for nuclei is a formidably difficult problem and is hard to do even today. The value $Z=173$ is far above the expected island of stability. As far as I know it isn't know how stable such large nuclei would be since the calculations are just too hard to do.

Answer (score 2):

This argument is based on the solutions of the Dirac equation for 1 electron in the field of a positive charge of Z=173 and a finite dimension. Assuming a point charge nucleus, the limit is $Z\leq 137$. To see what happens in the limit you have to look at the orbitals. A subject worth pursuing.

Whether such heavy nuclei can exist is a totally different subject.

Comment: *It is true that the kinetic energy of an electron in such an orbital will be equal to or larger than mc2.* Classically? Semi-classically? Quantum-mechanically, the KE isn't single-valued, and there is a tail at $>mc^2$ even in hydrogen.

Comment: @Ben Crowell Quantumchemically.